# Floating panels left and right CSS

Tags: html, css, floating

I need to put two floating panels on a Map but the `float: right` doesn't work. please help.

I tried everything but seems like the `position: absolute` disable the `float: right` or something.

Is there any way to align the second panel (#floating-panel2) to the right without changing the align of the first panel (#floating-panel1) ?

I need something like this:
[image]

And this is my html and my css:

```css
    #wrapper { position: relative; }

    #floating-panel1 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 265px;
      top: 55px;
      left: 5px;
      z-index: 5000;
      background-color: rgb(66, 72, 79);
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(66, 72, 79);
      border-radius: 1px;
    }
    
    #floating-panel2 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 265px;
      top: 55px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 5000;
      background-color: rgb(66, 72, 79);
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(66, 72, 79);
      border-radius: 1px;
      float:right;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100vh">
      <div id="floating-panel1">
        <h1>PANEL 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="floating-panel2">
        <h1>PANEL 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Please Help

Comment: You probably have to choose between absolute positioning and floats.   In #floating-panel, try getting rid of float: right and left: 0px, and add right: 5px (putting it to the right using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? If yes, all you had to do is change `left: 5px` to `right: 5px` on the second panel.

```css
#wrapper { position: relative; }

    #floating-panel1 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 265px;
      top: 55px;
      left: 5px;
      z-index: 5000;
      background-color: rgb(66, 72, 79);
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(66, 72, 79);
      border-radius: 1px;
    }
    
    #floating-panel2 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 265px;
      top: 55px;
      right: 5px;
      z-index: 5000;
      background-color: rgb(66, 72, 79);
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(66, 72, 79);
      border-radius: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100vh">
      <div id="floating-panel1">
        <h1>PANEL 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="floating-panel2">
        <h1>PANEL 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display div with float:left and float:right and add the position to div1 position:absolute and div2 position:relative.

```css
   #wrapper { position: relative; }

#floating-panel1 { 
  width: 265px;
  top: 55px; 
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: rgb(66, 72, 79);
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(66, 72, 79);
  border-radius: 1px;
}

#floating-panel2 { 
  width: 265px;
  top: 55px; 
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: rgb(66, 72, 79);
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(66, 72, 79);
  border-radius: 1px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100vh">
      <div id="floating-panel1">
        <h1>PANEL 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="floating-panel2">
        <h1>PANEL 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```